# How to write a function that performs two operations?

Tags: function-construction

I am solving an entry-level exercise to practice on writing my own functions in Mathematica.

I want to build a function that accepts a matrix of size larger than 2×2.

1. The function will replace the {1,1} element with 0

And,

2. The function will replace the {2,2} element with 1

So the following 2 operations are needed to be performed:

```
ReplacePart[M, {1, 1} -> 0]
ReplacePart[M, {2, 2} -> 1]
```

How do you write a function that does 2 operations?

The only scheme I have seen so far is `myFunc[m_]:=m.m` or `myFunc[m_]:=ReplacePart[m_,{1,1}->0]` but how do you write a function that does 2 `ReplacePart`'s as I say here?

Comment: How about: ReplacePart[m, {{1, 1} -> 0, {2, 2} -> 1}]

Comment: @bills Well that answers my question locally, i.e. the robust nature of the WL allows the user to do specifically this. But what about an operation that can't be "concatenated" into one function and has to be performed in two separate commands? For example, ReplacePart as already mentioned and also return the mean of the matrix columns: `Mean[M]`

Comment: I am not able to understand the question. Why can't you separate the two commands by `;` in the function? I have code to show this, but I am sure I am overlooking something. A function can do more than one command.

Comment: I am afraid you are not overlooking anything. I just don't know how to use the `;`. Should I use `{}` after `:=`?

Comment: You might be looking for CompoundExpression (a la @Nasser). Or maybe you need your return value to have structure, like a list or something using a custom head, and you can just put the result of each operation in its appropriate place.

Comment: Try something like `f[arg_]:=Module[...]`.  Check the documentation for `SetDelayed` and `Module`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I just don't know how to use the ;.

Here is an example

```
foo[m_?MatrixQ /; Length[m] > 2] := Module[{M = m},
  M = ReplacePart[M, {1, 1} -> 0];
  M = ReplacePart[M, {2, 2} -> 1];
  M
  ]
```

And you you can do

```
(m = {{1, 2, 3}, {3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8}}) // MatrixForm
foo[m] // MatrixForm
```

The last expression in a function is its return value.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

> But can you do it without a module?

You can. But then you can't create local module variable. Any variable used will be global.

```
foo[m_?MatrixQ /; Length[m] > 2] := 
 (M = m;  M = ReplacePart[M, {1, 1} -> 0]; M = ReplacePart[M, {2, 2} -> 1]; M)

(m = {{1, 2, 3}, {3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8}}) // MatrixForm
foo[m] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In the above `M` used inside the `(....)` will be global now, which is not good.

Modules are a good thing (TM).

Comment: That solves some of the confusion. I know that `Module` is the better practice for defining your own functions, for reasons related to localizing variables. But can you do it without a module?

Comment: @tush added example without Module.

Answer (score 8):

You can chain functions in the sense that the output of one is used as the input of the next:

```
f[m_] := ReplacePart[ReplacePart[m, {1, 1} -> 0], {2, 2} -> 1]
```

The same thing looks cleaner when written in a more obviously sequential syntax: using [right composition](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RightComposition.html) or [left composition](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition.html) of [pure functions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/FunctionalProgramming.html), depending on preference,

```
g1 = ReplacePart[{1, 1} -> 0] /* ReplacePart[{2, 2} -> 1];
g2 = ReplacePart[{2, 2} -> 1] @* ReplacePart[{1, 1} -> 0];
```

They all give the same result:

```
f[{{2, 3}, {4, 5}}]
(*    {{0, 3}, {4, 1}}    *)

g1[{{2, 3}, {4, 5}}]
(*    {{0, 3}, {4, 1}}    *)

g2[{{2, 3}, {4, 5}}]
(*    {{0, 3}, {4, 1}}    *)
```